# iPhone detects CSV as XLS

Tags: iphone, ios, email-attachments, file-extension

My app is able to import CSV files from within email attachments on the iPhone.  Excel is used to generate the CSV files.

Initially I set the `Document Type` to `public.comma-separated-values-text`.

This works fine with Mac based CSV files.  But when Windows based CSV files are emailed, the iPhone treats them differently.  The quick view fails to work on them, and it labels them as .XLS files.

Sure enough, when I call `[csvFilenameString pathExtension]`, it should return "CSV", but instead returns "XLS".  But the actual filename extension ***IS*** ".csv"!

So to support this weirdness and still be able to read them in, I had to change my apps `Document Type` setting to `public.data`.

Of course now to iOS, my app looks like it's registered in supporting every file type for email attachments.

The only difference I could tell between the two CSV type files (Mac vs. Windows) is the EOL.  Mac uses LF, while Windows uses CRLF.

Still, I'm thinking iOS should be smarter to detect it properly as a CSV and not as an XLS.

Anyone else experience this?

Comment: I am not a MS office expert but I can tell you if the extension CSV it doesn't mean that it is CSV file, it could be XLS, for example try to change the extension of MS word from docx to doc it will work fine and still docs file.